# Clip-path inside a div

Tags: html, css, svg, clip-path

I'm trying to make a clip-path mask like this example:
http://html.blahlab.com/tato/
but I've got the following problem: the mask is on the top left of the page, and it doesn't "follow" the linked div like the example.

My page is: http://mmazza.com/

Comment: View the source of the example and do it like that then. What exactly is your question? If it's a problem with your code then we need to see that code.

Comment: Post your code then explain your problem

Comment: http://mmazza.com/ here's mine.

Comment: @user3653589 you need to insert the relevant code in the question itself. Posting an external ressource isn't good practice as the link might change/die

Answer (score 0):

Tried upto here

```css
/**
 * For modern browsers
 * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
 *    contenteditable attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
 *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
 *    that are clearfixed.
 * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
 *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
 */
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}

.container {
 width: 600px;
 margin: 50px auto;
 position: relative;
}
section {
 margin-top: 50px;
 position: relative;
 min-height: 250px;
}
.overflow .rect {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: #eaeaea;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.overflow .circle {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 border-radius: 100px;
 background-color: #601785;
 position: relative;
 left: 100px;
}

.clip .circle {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 border-radius: 100px;
 background-color: #601785;
 position: absolute;
 clip: rect(0px,100px,200px,0px);
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.text h1 {
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 5em;
 text-align: center;

 background-image: url(http://demo.hongkiat.com/css-masking/Galaxy.jpg);

 -webkit-background-clip: text;
 background-clip: text;

 color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<link href="http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/2.0.1/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Masking and Clipping on the Web</title>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <style>
 h1{
  font-size:90px;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">


<section class="text cf">

<h1>CLIP</h1>




</section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```